# Best Unit Testing Framework for testing WP7 application

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-phone-7

I want to know which is the best unit testing framework for testing WP7 applications. It would be great if the testing framework supports functional testing also. I should be able to run the tests on my device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com) contains the de-facto Unit Testing framework.

Roger Peters [wrote a guide how on how to use it](http://smartypantscoding.com/a-cheat-sheet-for-unit-testing-silverlight-apps-on-windows-phone-7)

Comment: Claus thanks for your reply ,Does the Silverlight Toolkit provide functional testing also.It would be great if I can find some good examples for functional testing also.